# Cannot Find getWindow(Applet) in netscape.javascript.JSObject

Tags: java, compiler-errors, applet, drjava, jsobject

I am trying to call JavaScript functions from a JApplet. I've searched through tutorials and they say that I need to import and use netscape.javascript.* from my \jre\lib\plugin.jar

I did import netscape.javascript.* and I'm using DrJava, and it kept saying it cannot find the getWindow method.

This is the error it gives me:
(MinesweeperApplet extends JApplet)

```
Error: cannot find symbol  
    symbol:   method getWindow(MinesweeperApplet)  
    location: class netscape.javascript.JSObject
```

This is the piece of code inside the MinesweeperApplet class where I am trying to get the JSObject:

```
public void start(){                
    // add stuff    
    JSObject window = JSObject.getWindow(this);    
    Container cp = getContentPane();
    ...
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: *"I'm using DrJava"*  ..to run the applet?  How are you testing it?  AFAIU no (development) environment short of a 'browser' will have the functionality of the `JSObject`.

Comment: I meant I'm using DrJava (as opposed to NetBeans or Eclipse) to write and compile the Java source code. And the error message I gave above is given by DrJava's compiler. The Java application by itself works fine, I even tested in browser. But when I tried to add Java-to-Javascript communication, this problem came.

Comment: *"to write and compile"*  Right.  Silly me.  :P  Sorry, don't know much about DrJAva and setting the Compile time class-path in it.  Does it run Ant build files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the "solution."

Previously I was using JDK 7. Then I downloaded and tried JDK 6 (update 45) and it could compile fine. And from that point on, the Java-to-Javascript communication works.